# What is the difference of meaning between "a bigger size" and "a size bigger"?

Tags: meaning, adjective-position

I read the two forms.
I learned that the adjective is before the noun but I guess that there are some exceptions.
Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: Personally, I think "_larger_" in both phrases sounds slightly more natural (more so for "_a larger size_") although from e.g. [this transcript](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page24.shtml) it seems "_big_" / "_bigger_" is more common. This doesn't affect the difference _between_ the two phrases though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "a size bigger", "size" is used as a unit of measurement.

This usage presumes that whatever is being discussed (clothing, drink servings, etc.) comes in a discrete set of possible sizes.  Thus, for example, if a café serves coffee in "small", "medium", "large" and "extra-large" cups, then a medium coffee would be "a size bigger" than a small coffee (and a large coffee would be *two* sizes bigger than a small, and an extra-large would be *three* sizes bigger than a small).

Compare this with other similar unit-based comparisons, like "He's an inch taller than her" or "This road is a mile longer than the other one" or "This ladder is two steps taller than that one."

On the other hand, "a bigger size" simply refers to *any* size that is bigger than the one it's compared to.  So, in the same café example as above, "medium", "large" and "extra-large" would all be bigger sizes than "small".

Comment: Thank you. That is very clear.

Answer (score 5):

"a size bigger" means  the next size. More like a unit and discrete. 
"a bigger size" means any other size as long is bigger. Continuous and unlimited.

"That building is a brick taller. That's why this building needs a taller brick"

Comment: Sorry Alex, I don't I've ever heard the phrase "a taller brick" can you tell me where it comes from?

Answer (score 3):

"A size bigger" is more specific than "A bigger size". If a lady tries on a size 12 dress and finds that it is just a bit too small she might ask an assistant for one "A size bigger", in which case she should be offered the same dress in a size 14 (in the US and UK there are no odd-numbered sizes). If the size 12 was much too small she might ask for one in "A bigger size" in which case the assistant should offer offer a size 14, 16, 18 or even bigger.